# $k[t]/(f_1(t)) \cong k[t]/(f_2(t))$ as modules iff $f_1 = f_2.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $t$ is transcendental over $k$ and suppose $f_1, f_2$ are polynomials with leading coefficient 1. I want to show that $k[t]/(f_1(t)) \cong k[t]/(f_2(t))$ iff $f_1 = f_2.$ My book (Lang's Algebra) says to decompose each polynomial into prime powers and apply the structure theorem for modules over principal rings. But I am not sure how to do this. The structure theorem says that for a given finitely generated module $M$ over a principal ring $R,$ we have an isomorphism $M \cong \oplus R/(p_i)$ where the $(p_i)$ are primary ideals and the $p_i$ are unique up to unit multiples. So if $f_1$ were to decompose as $f_1 = p_1^{k_1} \ldots p_l^{k_1}$ then by Chinese Remainder Theorem, we would have the isomorphism $k[t]/f_1 \cong k[t]/(p_1^{k_1}) \oplus \ldots \oplus k[t]/(p_l^{k_1}).$ The same isomorphism is also a module isomorphism. We can also see that each $(p_i^{k_i})$ is a primary ideal. So we can do the same for $k[t]/f_2 \cong k[t]/(q_1^{j_1}) \oplus \ldots \oplus (q_m^{j_m})$. The structure theorem tells us this decomposition is unique (up to unit multiples).

Now my question is: Does the structure theorem for modules tell us that $m = l?$ Also, since each of the $p_i^{k_i}$ is a unit multiple of some $q_e^{j_e}$ we can conclude that $f_1 = f_2.$ Is my reasoning correct? I want to make sure my understanding is correct.

Comment: Are you sure about this result? A counterexample is $$\Bbb R [t] / (t^2+1) \cong \Bbb R [t] / (t^2+2)$$ indeed these two fields are isomorphic to $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @Crostul I suspect the OP means isomorphism of $k[t]$-modules rather than as $k$-algebras.

Comment: He probably forgot to say that the two are isomorphic as k[t]-modules. But in this case the answer is trivial: isomorphic modules have the same annihilator. (Discussed on this site many times before.)

Comment: Just think about the annihilators of each side.

Comment: Hmm ok so the annihilator of $k[t]/f_1$ would be the ideal $(f_1)$ of $k[t]$ but the annihilator of $k[t]/f_2$ would be the ideal $(f_2)$. So obviously if the modules are the same then the annihilators are the same so $f_1 = f_2$ if they are both monic. Is this what you're getting at @LordSharktheUnknown. This argument seems a lot better but is my argument that I wrote any good as well?

Comment: @伽罗瓦 exactly!${}$